# Python Index column doesn't freeze while scrolling to the right

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

my problem is that I have a Dataframe of 200 rows and 200 columns, while I scroll to the right the index column stay fixed ( I can still see it) as it should be. 
However when I select a column or value into the Dataframe (for example to order the values in ascending or descending order), the index column change and becomes the same as the column I selected.
I would like to still see the index column.

I am using Spyder 3.3.0 and Python 3.6

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import operator

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('1992_2014.csv', index_col =0)

nations_all = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
nations = [nations_all[0]]
for i in range(0, len(nations_all)):
    if nations_all[i] not in nations:
        nations.append(nations_all[i])

Year = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
CO2 = dataset.iloc[:, 8].values



# Creating the Trend Matrix between two nations
trend_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index = nations, columns = nations)
for i in nations:
    n = dataset[dataset["Nation"] == i].index.values.astype(int)
    for k in nations:
        kn = dataset[dataset["Nation"] == k].index.values.astype(int)
        div_n = CO2[n[0]]
        div_kn = CO2[kn[0]]
        CO2_n = (CO2[n]/div_n)
        CO2_kn = (CO2[kn]/div_kn)

        trend_matrix.loc[i, k] =   sum(list(map(abs,list(map(operator.sub, CO2_n, CO2_kn)))))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add your code to your post? It's hard to tell what is going wrong without seeing what you have tried first.

Comment: Ei Karl, I added the code.